# proving that an arithmetic sequence is equal to a geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, word-problem

how can I prove that an arithmetic sequence is equal to a geometric sequence if and only if the initial values of the sequences are the same and the common difference of the arithmetic sequence is 0; the common ratio of the geometric sequence is 1?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

If $a-d,a,a+d,a+2d,\cdots$ are also in Geometric progression,

$(a-d)(a+d)=a^2\implies d=?$

What will be common ratio?

Alternatively, if $b,br,br^2,\cdots$ are also in arithmetic progression,

$b+br^2=2br\implies b(r-1)^2=0$

For non-trivial cases, $b\ne0$

Answer (score 0):

The difference between any two consecutive terms of an arithmetic sequence is a constant $d$.  Then the ratio between any two consecutive terms is $\frac {a_k + d}{a_k} = 1 + \frac d{a_k}$ which is in general not constant unless the $a_k$s are all equal.  (in which case $a_{k+1} -a_k = d =0$ and $a_{k+1} = a_k$ and the sequence is constant.)

The ratio between any two consecutive terms of a geometric sequence is a constant $d$.  Then the difference between any two consecutive terms is $b*a_k - a_k = (b-1)*a_k$ which is in general not constant unless either $b =1 $ (in which case $a_{k+1} = a_k*1 = a_k$ and the sequence is constant) or the $a_k$ are all equal (in which case the sequence is constant and $b = 1$... unless all the terms are $0$ in which case the value of $b$ is irrelevent).

So the only way a sequence can only be *both* arithmetic and geometric if both the difference and the ratios of consecutive terms are constant and the only way *that* can occur is if the sequence is constant and $d = 0$ and $b =0$ and the sequence is $a_0, a_0, a_0,.......$